# Fragment navigation issue

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a fragment which contains a list.Upon selecting one element from the list it navigate to another fragment with some specific data.
When I back pressed from fragment 2, I get fragment 1 where the list is showing twice.

fragment1 before back pressed

[image: before backpressed]

Fragment1 after back pressed

[image: after Backpressed]

Below is my fragment transaction code from Fragment1 to Fragment2

```
    fragmentManager = mainActivityContext.getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
    SurveyOverView surveyOverView = new SurveyOverView();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putParcelable("SURVEY_QUESTION",surveys.get(position));
    surveyOverView.setArguments(bundle);      fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,surveyOverView,FRAG_TAG);
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);

    fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Please help I do not know how to resolve this.

Comment: it's your adapter issue. post your fragment1 code

Comment: Can you show your fragment code in which you add survey data in your list ?

Comment: You need to clear your list while loading another time. post code of list while adding data.

Comment: Yes. I did that now and it is working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The most possible reason of this issue is you've added data to existing list without clearing its current data first. Post your code for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the help... I cleared the data inside oncreateView before loading data and it worked.